# Mutual information between two dependent variables

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable such that
\begin{equation}
X = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{with p = 1/3} \\
-1 & \text{with p= 1/3} \\
0 & \text{with p = 1/3}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and let $Y = X^2$ whose distribution is
\begin{equation}
Y = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{with p = 2/3} \\
0 & \text{with p = 1/3}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Note that it is clear that $Y$ is completely determined by $X$.
However, $X$ can not be completely determined by $Y$.

It follows from
$$ P(X=a,Y=b) = P(Y=b|X=a)P(X=a)$$
that we have the following joint distribution of $(X,Y)$,
$$P(X=1,Y=1) = P(X=-1,Y=1) = P(X=0,Y=0) = 1/3.$$
Note that $P(Y=b|X=a)$ is either 1 or 0, as $Y$ is completely determined by $X$.

Therefore, we compute the mutual information of $X$ and $Y$ and obtain
$$ I(X;Y) = \sum_{(x,y)} p(x,y)\log \left(\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)}\right)
= \frac{1}{3}\log(3^3/4) > 0 $$
[Editted] Previously, wrong computation.

Based on [the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Motivation)

> "Intuitively, mutual information measures the information that X and Y
>   share: It measures how much knowing one of these variables reduces
>   uncertainty about the other."

**Question**
In this example, knowing $X$ completely reduces uncertainty in $Y$.
Then how should I interpret this value $I(X;Y) = \frac{1}{3}\log(3^3/2) > 0$
in order to draw a conclusion that
"$Y$ can be completely determined by $X$"?

**My thought**
I think the mutual information of $X, Y=X^2$, doesn't make sense,
as knowing $X$ completely determines $Y$, however, 
knowing $Y$ does not.
This is because $I(X;Y) = I(Y;X)$.
That is by changing the role of $X$ and $Y$, we obtain the same value even knowing the fact that $X$ completely determines $Y$ but $Y$ doesn't.
This doesn't sound right to me.

It would be very appreciated if someone gives some comments or suggestions or any thoughts.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you notice the $I(X;Y) = H(X) - H(X|Y)$ formula? Is that not suitable for an interpretation?

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks for your comment. I am aware of that formula. However, entropy doesn't help me much. I understand entropy Η(X) is a measure of uncertainty about a random variable X. But it is not clear to interpret an actual number into drawing a reasonable conclusion, unless it is 0. For example, if I(X;Y) = 0, we can say that X and Y are independent. If I(X;Y) > 0, what can we say about X and Y? except for X and Y are not independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intuition that "$Y$ can be completely determined by $X$" is verified only by the fact that $H(Y|X)=0$, i.e., "given $X$, there is no uncertainty in $Y$". The fact that $I(X,Y)>0$ is irrelevant. The value of $I(X;Y)$ quantifies the information that can be transfered when the "data" is $X$ and $Y$ is the "observation" or vice versa. In this case, since $Y$ is a well defined function of $X$, it is intuitive that the mutual information will be positive (i.e., observing $Y$ gives information about $X$ and vice versa). Actually, it will always hold $I(X;Y)>0$, unless $Y,X$ are independent random variables, resulting in $I(X;Y)=0$.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you so much for your comment! One more thing is that is there any other interpretation on I(X;Y) >0 except for X and Y are dependent?

Comment: @induction601 Mutual information is a quantity that is much more useful than simply stating that two random variables are independent or not (the latter is provided by their joint distribution in the first place). It is essential in applications such as channel coding (reliably transfer information via a "channel") and data compression. You may want to study some introductory text on information theory for further details.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is unclear how you quickly come to log(3/4) in the last step; probably you calculated the marginals wrongly. $p(x)=1/3$ for all x where $p(x)$ is not vanishing. $p(Y=1)=2/3$ and $p(Y=0)$ equals 1/3. So you have
$$I=1/3(\log(\frac{1/3}{1/3* 1/3})+\log(\frac{1/3}{2/3 *1/3})+\log(\frac{1/3}{2/3 *1/3}))$$
$$=1/3 (\log(3)+ 2*log(3/2))$$
which is positive.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I noticed I made a mistake on the computation and modified my question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the case $ x = 1 $ and $ y = 1 $. The fraction inside the log is $ \frac{ \frac{1}{3} }{ \frac{1}{3} \frac{2}{3} } = 1.5 $.
It is the same for $ x = -1 $ and $ y = 1 $. 
For $ x = 0 $ and $ y = 0 $ we have $ \frac{ \frac{1}{3} }{ \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{3} } = 3 $.

So the $ \log \left( \cdot \right) $ argument is always bigger than 1 and all is OK.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I noticed my mistake and modified my question. It would be appreciated if you take a look again on my question.

Answer (score 1):

Y is fully determined from X simply means that H(Y|X)=0 which implies that I(X:Y)=H(Y)-H(Y|X)=H(Y), which is what you have here.

The fact that X is not fully determined by Y means that H(X|Y)>0 which again implies that I(X:Y)< H(X). That also makes sense, since H(X) > H(Y). The uncertainty of X must be bigger, that's why it cannot be fully determined by Y to begin with.

If you draw Venn diagrams it becomes very clear. The circle representing Y  would be entirely inside X.